# upgrading from Django 1.6 to 1.7

Tags: python, django

I cannot work out how to upgrade from Django 1.6 to 1.7.
This appeared to work:

```
sudo pip install -U django
```

But this still reports 1.6:

```
import django
django.VERSION
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`import django django.VERSION` will give you the current installed version of Django. Try installing python setuptools package found [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools). Then try the following commands

```
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
sudo easy_install --upgrade django
```

You can find more help [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/upgrade-version/) and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/install/#installing-official-release) on how to upgrade the Django. Good luck!